# How to make Spring Data REST endpoints asynchronous?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-data, spring-data-rest, completable-future

Does anyone know how to make Spring Data REST endpoints asynchronous?

I saw that we can add the annotation `@Async` with `CompletableFuture<?>` as returned object on the service methods.
But doing this, makes the use of the interface `RepositoryRestResource` pointless as we need to implement both the service and controller layers manually...

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Spring Data REST supports blocking I/O only. See this [Jira Issue of Spring Data REST support for Spring WebFlux](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-933).

Spring MVC has an integration with Servlet 3.0 [async request processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async).

Although Spring MVC has async support, for non-blocking I/O, [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) is recommended, because Spring WebFlux is async by design. See [Spring Web MVC Async Request Compared to WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async-vs-webflux)